# MYsqli create table primary and unique key auto increment

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a table with one primary key and one unique key (unique key I would like to use for row order). Not sure if this is the best way, but I want a table with songs that can be ordered in specific way so I wanted a column (order_id) to control order.

I am getting this error when I try to create table:

Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `music` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: I wonder what's unclear with error message

Comment: I could swear I read somewhere that its possible to have more than one auto increment column, but I cant find it anymore. So I guess I am wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to say that 2 auto incrementing columns in not necessary. They would both contain the same numbers.

UNIQUE will only allow a unique value in that column so you can generate a a unique id or use a unique id generator.

It could look like....

```
function F_gen_unique_id($tbl, $fld, $max_num = 6){
                                $tmp = false
    while($i < 8 && $ok == false){
                                $tmp = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', mt_rand(1,$max_num))), 1, $max_num);
                                $chk = (int)my_database_class("SELECT * FROM `".$tbl."` WHERE ".$fld." = '".$tmp."'","row_count");
        if($chk === 0){
                                $ok = true;
                                break;
        }
                                $i++;
    }
                                return $tmp;
}
```

Then use it...  `$my_unique_id = F_gen_unique_id('music', 'order_id', 12);`